# Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm training a model using tensorflow and everything is working perfectly fine until the epoch ends then I get the error below ... what does this mean??

System info(Google colab):

- GPU 0: Tesla K80 (UUID: GPU-26ddd2bb-3c0f-4772-1bc9-077417190d42)
- tensorflow version: 2.1
- Cuda: 10.1
- Platform: Ubuntu 18

Here are the steps I do:

```
training_size = sum(1 for _ in tf.data.TFRecordDataset(self.train_tf_record))

history = self.training_model.fit(training_gen,
                                      epochs=epochs,
                                      callbacks=callbacks,
                                      validation_data=valid_gen,
                                      steps_per_epoch=training_size / batch_size)
```

`train_gen` and `valid_gen` are both generators obtained by:

```
dataset = dataset.prefetch(
    buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
image, label = next(iter(dataset.take(1)))
while True:
    yield image, label
```

I'm using generators because if I pass both datasets directly to `model.fit()` the training is killed by the oom killer as soon as something gets out of memory

And NOTE that if I do not specify `steps_per_epoch` the epoch never ends, it just keeps stepping forever up to 800 steps+ and then I interrupt the execution because the dataset is not that large(around 2200 images)

then this happens after the first epoch:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/context.py", line 2039, in execution_mode
    yield
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py", line 668, in _next_internal
    output_shapes=self._flat_output_shapes)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_dataset_ops.py", line 2552, in iterator_get_next
    _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 6810, in raise_from_not_ok_status
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: indices[154] = [6, -2, 18, 0] does not index into shape [8,52,52,3,6]
     [[{{node PartitionedCall_2/TensorScatterUpdate}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trainer.py", line 265, in <module>
    tr.train(100, 8, 1e-4, dataset_name='beverly_hills')
  File "../Helpers/utils.py", line 33, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "trainer.py", line 248, in train
    steps_per_epoch=training_size / batch_size)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 71, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 940, in fit
    return_dict=True)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 71, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1150, in evaluate
    steps_per_execution=self._steps_per_execution)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 1138, in __init__
    model=model)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 787, in __init__
    peek, x = self._peek_and_restore(x)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 845, in _peek_and_restore
    peek = next(x)
  File "trainer.py", line 150, in initialize_dataset
    image, label = next(iter(dataset.take(1)))
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py", line 644, in __next__
    return self.next()
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py", line 683, in next
    return self._next_internal()
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py", line 674, in _next_internal
    return structure.from_compatible_tensor_list(self._element_spec, ret)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 99, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/context.py", line 2042, in execution_mode
    executor_new.wait()
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/executor.py", line 67, in wait
    pywrap_tfe.TFE_ExecutorWaitForAllPendingNodes(self._handle)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: indices[154] = [6, -2, 18, 0] does not index into shape [8,52,52,3,6]
     [[{{node PartitionedCall_2/TensorScatterUpdate}}]]
2020-04-27 13:07:24.909888: W tensorflow/core/kernels/data/generator_dataset_op.cc:103] Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: Failed precondition: Python interpreter state is not initialized. The process may be terminated.
     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
```

Comment: If your train goes well until the end of the epoch it seems that your validation data is wrong. The error message is saying about shapes problems. So, check your train_gen and validation_gen, and see if they are yielding same shape always

Comment: Both are the output of the same method and I tested the whole code on smaller datasets, it runs perfectly fine, all kinds of problems started to happen when using a large dataset

Comment: It's hard to say what is wrong without seem your model. Reading the error message, seems that is a shape problem in your validation data. If your model input has a static input shape, check if your generators always yield the same shape as model input

Comment: @Augusto Maillo I just found that there was some bug that I overlooked in the pandas dataframe fed to the trainer i fixed it and will test again to see if the problem is gone

Comment: Cool! Dont forget to edit your question after or if is the case close it.

Comment: Sure, I will after it's gone

Comment: @Augusto Maillo problem remains

Comment: Could you post a reproducible piece of code? Seems i need you _dataset_ object and your _model_ to reproduce this. You can comment your colab notebook link too and i will try to help you.

Comment: @AugustoMaillo okay, you may check the code here https://github.com/emadboctorx/yolov3-keras-tf2 and thanks in advance, if you have any questions let me know

Comment: @AugustoMaillo and here's the colab link, if you prefer https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1vEf-rxuTvf-PvV5s6QKVXTudWX069GQI

Comment: Hi @sK500 I too have a similar error. Could you please let me know how did you fix this?

Comment: @prb_cm mine was a problem with the dataset, try experimenting with a sample and see when it happens.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error.
Then I used the `tf-nightly` command:

```
!pip install tf-nightly
```

Changed my loss to categorical cross-entropy and it started training.

Comment: I solved this issue a while back ago, I don't remember the exact details but from what I can recall it was a dataset issue